# Gif to Lottie(Json) without bg

Tags: json, animation, gif, lottie

I need to convert a GIF to lottie without a background, the only option is to do it with a sequencing and import into lottie right?

https://observablehq.com/@forresto/video-to-lottie

I tried through this site, but there was still a background, I also uploaded with the format mov edited to this video without a background, but it did not work